# Overloading a function defined in a namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

Why is the following code illegal?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace what {
void print(int count) {
    cout << count << endl;
}
}

void what::print(const string& str) {
    cout << str << endl;
}

int main() {
    what::print(1);
    what::print("aa");

    return 0;
}
```

The error I get when compiling with clang and `-std=c++14` is

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'print' does not match any declaration in namespace 'what'
```

I know the fix to the problem but I am wondering why the compiler thinks that I am trying to define the function (`print`) instead of overload it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is not working for you is because the syntax

```
void what::print(const string& str)
```

is basically saying

> inside the `what` namespace, define the `print` function here

If you want to define a function outside of its namespace, you must declare it in the namespace beforehand.

> §13.1 of the standard states, *"When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name in the same scope, that name is said
>   to be overloaded."*

Overloads of a function must be in the same scope of each other. It is just how the language works.

Comment: "Overloads of a function must be in the same namespace of each other."  But isn't that what `what::` is attempting to do?  I think the emphasis should be more on *in the same scope*.  Attempting to overload a function from a different namespace is certainly a different scope.

Comment: @Mr.Llama fixed my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Llama exactly why I asked this question!

Comment: @GregM Just curious, where did you get the standard from?  I would also like to get a copy.  I saw on isocpp.com that you have to pay for one.  Is that required or is there an online copy somewhere that I can obtain legally?

Comment: @Curious - If you google the exact phrase from Greg's answer ("When two or more ... overloaded") you'll find a few places online that have it.  The first example I found is [here](http://www.lcdf.org/c%2B%2B/), but it's not the latest C++14 standard.  You can also get the [C++14 November 2014 working draft](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) for free as a PDF.  From the same link, you can also find the C++17 draft.

Comment: @Curious There is a free working draft available for viewing at https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard. The reason that is free is because it's not a "finalized" copy yet. Just look for "Where To Get Working Drafts (draft C++17)" and in that section there should be a link for the draft.